# Python: calling strings from a list to feed into a function

Tags: python, loops, finance

I'm struggling with how to correctly feed a list of strings one-by-one into a pre-defined function. The list looks like this:

```
riclist = ["XAU=", "XAG=", "XPT=", "XPD="]
```

And the function looks like this (note that ek.get_timeseries is a pre-defined function from the Eikon library, but this problem could be generalized to any similar one):

```
def get_variable(input):

    chosenric = riclist[ ##each item one-by-one## ]

    var = ek.get_timeseries(rics=chosenric, 
                            start_date=2018-01-01,
                            fields="CLOSE") 

    return(var)
```

And the end result I'm after is a DataFrame with the time-series for all n variables in riclist.

Comment: why not loop through your list of strings? `for mystr in riclist: ek.get_timeseries(rics=chosenric, 
                            start_date=2018-01-01,
                            fields="CLOSE") `

Comment: Wait a second.., You have an argument `input` (which should be renamed because it is overwriting the existing `input` function) which is never used

Comment: can you provide an example without `ek.get_timeseries`? have you read about [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: What does `ek.get_timeseries` return, e.g. list, array, series, something else?

Comment: if you need a dataFrame from a list just do pd.DataFrame(riclist) where pd is a pandas library. you can add the time field after that.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for item in riclist:
    var = ek.get_timeseries(rics=chosenric, 
                        start_date=2018-01-01,
                        fields="CLOSE")
    ....do the rest here for each item
```

Comment: following OP `item` should be renamed to `chosenric`

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something in the question, but if the question is:

How to run a function on a list of arguments then 
there are a few simple ways:

1. `results = [get_variable(input) for input in riclist]`
2. `results = map(get_variable, riclist)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I completely understand your question, but are you looking for a for loop?

```
for ric in riclist:
    var = ek.get_timeseries(rics=ric, 
                            start_date=2018-01-01,
                            fields="CLOSE")
```

then, if you want to return one at a time, you could use a [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/6866529)

```
    yield var
```

Comment: This works to an extent - I can define the function and generate an output using "yield", the problem is storing the result as a DataFrame where the columns are each of the variables in "riclist".

Answer (score 0):

Returns a dict-like {chosenric : timeseries}

```
def get_variable(riclist):
    return {chosenric : ek.get_timeseries(rics=chosenric, start_date=2018-01-01, fields="CLOSE") for chosenric in riclist}
```

Comment: This also works well - but any help converting the output to a DataFrame rather than a dict?

Comment: Doesn't this work? :
df = pd.DataFrame(data=get_variable(riclist))


If not, send me the output you got from the function I wrote.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work - ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: Try it like this then:

`def get_variable(riclist):
    return {chosenric : [ek.get_timeseries(rics=chosenric, start_date=2018-01-01, fields="CLOSE")] for chosenric in riclist}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=get_variable(riclist))`

(Sorry, cant paste code in here properly, i guess)

Comment: It doesn't quite work - the entire time-series for a single column is fit into a single cell (so the DataFrame is a 1x4 size)

Comment: If you can send me the output of my function would be great, because I can't use "ek". Otherwise I'll be here just "non-sense" trying.

Comment: In: df
    Out: 
                                                XAG=  \
0  XAG=         CLOSE
Date              
2018-07-...   

                                                XAU=  \
0  XAU=            CLOSE
Date                 
20...   

                                                XPD=  \
0  XPD=         CLOSE
Date              
2018-07-...   

                                                XPT=  
0  XPT=         CLOSE
Date              
2018-07-...  

Each ticker (XAG=, XAU= etc) is its own cell in the DataFrame with the entire time series crammed in it

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better to ask these kind of questions on the [Thomson Reuters Developer Portal](https://community.developers.thomsonreuters.com/index.html), because you are asking something (licensed) product specific, which is not useful for the StackOverflow community.

That being said, the `get_timeseries` function can be fed a list of instruments directly. It always returns a pandas dataframe. So you probably want to do this:

```
df = ek.get_timeseries(riclist, fields="CLOSE", start_date='2018-01-01')
```

If you really need it to be part of a function, you could do this:

```
def get_variable():

    var = ek.get_timeseries(rics=riclist, 
                            start_date="2018-01-01",
                            fields="CLOSE") 

    return(var)
```

Please check out the [documentation](https://developers.thomsonreuters.com/eikon-apis/eikon-data-apis/docs)

**Disclaimer: I am currently employed by Thomson Reuters